# Line Integrals on Closed Loops

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am working on a problem that requires finding the line integral of a vector field along a curve.
The vector field is defined by the function:

> $$F(x,y)=\left(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2},\frac{-x}{x^2+y^2}\right)$$

which is well defined everywhere except the point $(0,0)$, where it is not defined.

The line integral to be done is across the curve defined by:

> $$(\cos(t),-\sin(t)),t\in[0,2\pi]$$

The curve is closed, as can be seen and the vector field is conservative as it can be shown to be the gradient of the function $U(x,y)=\arctan\left(\frac xy\right)$

This means that the line integral should be $0$, as the line integral of a conservative vector field over a closed curve is $0$. However after computing it by hand it turns out to be $2\pi$. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use Green's Theorem, it requires continuous partial derivatives on an open region that contains the interior of the curve.  So do most of the other relevant theorems.  Since your function is not continuous at the origin, most of the theorems do not apply.